# parsing options in a config module

Tags: python, command-line, python-3.x

I use config module to store variables global to all modules. Is it a good place to parse the script arguments? (Note: config module is my own module, it just contains a bunch of global variables.)

```
----- config.py -----
from optparse import OptionParser

parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-t", "--test", action = "store_true", dest = "test")
#add other options here
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()

------ file1.py ------
import config.py

if config.options.test:
   #do something

------ file2.py ------
import config.py

if config.options.test:
   #do something
```

I am concerned about executing the `parse_args()` function in a file other than the "main" file (invoked from the command line).

Comment: 1) When you import a file, you don't need the '.py', just "import config". 2) With your current config.py, parse_args() will execute every time the file is imported.

Comment: Ah, that makes it not a good idea. Thank you -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to do? There are 2 ways you can try -

1. Pass argument values to your program from command-line (using `optparse`).
2. or write a `config.py` import it in your program & proceed.

Why would you want to do both (& that too in your `config` file)?

I see that you have written your `config` module as `.py` (which is good). But this file should contain minimal code in it. Just config settings. It would help you to keep code & config separate.

The general rule I follow is, if the arguments that need to be passed to my program is more than 6-7, I use a config file. Otherwise `optparse` it is.

Comment: That's a good point. I guess I was thinking I would just put --verbose and --file filename into the command line arguments. Since those change so often, I thought opening config.py for that would be silly. But I guess I can combine everything into config.py.

Comment: it might be confusing for the user to put some options in a `config` file & some in command-line. Better swing either way completely.